# vb.net syntax for order by clause in linq to sql that has select new with

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ to sql statement that joins 2 tables. I would like to add a order by clause on one of the columns. However the order by clause does not seem to take effect at all.

Could you please suggest the right syntax in VB.net to achieve order by in the following:

```
Dim query = From dtIt In dbsomecontext.mytable
             Join dtIl In dbsomecontext.anothertable On dtIt.ItemID Equals dtIl.ItemID
             Where dtIl.IsAvailable = True
                    Order By dtIt.manufacturer
                    Select New With {
                                        .Alpha = UCase((dtIt.manufacturer).Substring(0, 1))
                                    }

    Dim dtManufacturer As DataTable = csLINQOperations.LINQToDataTable(query)
    Return dtManufacturer
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you put a break point on the line where to Dim dtManufacturer ?

I created some sample classes to repersent your data objects as you've defined it.

```
    Dim linqQuery = From dtIT In myTables _
                    Join dtIL In otherTables On dtIT.ItemID Equals dtIL.ItemID _
                    Where dtIL.IsAvaliable = True _
                    Order By dtIT.Manufacturer Ascending _
                    Select New With {.Alpha = UCase((dtIT.Manufacturer).Substring(0, 1))}
```

Now, when I have a break point on the line after this LINQ Query I can inspect the object linqQuery by using "linqQuery.ToList" and see the order of the data. It does infact order the output in an ordered fashion, based on the Manufacturer name.

Why is it that you think your code is not ordering the data? Using the Break Points and Watch, inspect your "query" object (using "query.ToList" in the Quick Watch) and see if the results are ordered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I figured the results were not ordered by "QuickWatch"ing dtManufacturer in the line :
 Dim dtManufacturer As DataTable = csLINQOperations.LINQToDataTable(query)

Now, I have changed the query to as follows and it works :
 Dim query = From dtIt In dbinkAndToner.InkAndToners
                    Join dtIl In dbinkAndToner.ItemsLists On dtIt.ItemID Equals dtIl.ItemID
                    Where dtIl.IsAvailable = True
                    Select New With {
                                        .Alpha = ((dtIt.Manufacturer).Substring(0, 1))
                                    }
                                Distinct

```
    query = From dtIt In query
            Order By dtIt.Alpha

    Dim dtManufacturer As DataTable = csLINQOperations.LINQToDataTable(query)
    Return dtManufacturer
```